# Show files that are in Git's index and changed in the working copy

Tags: git, git-diff, pre-commit-hook, git-index

I have a Git pre-commit hook which strips whitespace and leaves the modified files in the working copy, so that it doesn't stomp on a partial add like `git add -p`.

If I commit one file out of many changed, and whitespace is corrected, I then have two files changed in the working copy and one staged file (which is also in the working copy, but the staged change has whitespace errors):

```
vi fileWithBadWS.txt  # leave bad whitespace
vi fileWithGoodWS.txt # don't leave bad whitespace
vi unrelatedFile.txt

git add fileWithBadWS.txt fileWithGoodWS.txt 
git commit -m "Commited files, one with bad whitespace" # pre-commit hook fails
```

The repo now looks like this:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:

        modified:   fileWithBadWS.txt  # bad WS
        modified:   fileWithGoodWS.txt

Changes not staged for commit:

        modified:   fileWithBadWS.txt   # fixed WS
        modified:   unrelatedFile.txt
```

I can use:

- `git diff` to see `fileWithBadWS.txt` and `unrelatedFile.txt`
- `git diff --cached` to see staged files `fileWithBadWS.txt` and `fileWithGoodWS`.

How can I see *only* the files that are both modified in the working copy and staged (i.e. just `fileWithBadWS.txt`)?

Note: this question uses whitespace and pre-commit hooks as an example, but applies more generally to any situation when you have some files staged and some not, with some overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this ?

`git diff --name-only --staged | xargs git diff --name-only`

This would show you files which are staged as well as changed in the working tree.

Comment: For unusual filenames `git diff --name-only --staged -z | xargs -0 git diff --name-only` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff `git diff --name-only --cached`
```

there are 2 parts:

`git diff --name-only --cached` - get file names of staged files

`git diff file_list` - list the changes on those files